# Visualization of correlated elements of 2 data frames

Tags: python, r, ggplot2

I’m doing some statistical analysis on geometrical data. I have two data frames containing 79 elements and 3 features (x,y,z) and I found the best correlation between different elements of these two data frames. For example, x,y,z of element N°1 of data frame A have a good correlation with x,y,z of element N°15 of data frame B. Now, I want to have 3D visualization of these correlations. Right now, I have two 3D plots with plot3d() of ggplot. But I want them to be in one figure (combining the 2 plots) and draw a line between the elements that have a correlation with each other. I mean put my actual plots in front of each other and connect the related elements with lines.
Could you please help me with the solution in R(preferably) or even Pyhon.[image]

My code below is for having the plots:

```
# plot of the first dataset
    plot3d( 
      x=matrix_simp[,1], y=matrix_simp[,2], z=matrix_simp[,3], 
      col = mycolors, 
      type = 's', 
      radius = .02,
      xlab="x", ylab="y", zlab="z")
    
    # plot of the second dataset
    plot3d( 
      x=livewire_corps$x, y=livewire_corps$y, z=livewire_corps$z, 
      col = 'royalblue1', 
      type = 's', 
      radius = .02,
      xlab="x", ylab="y", zlab="z")
```

And my first dataset is like this (I transformed it as ma matrix)

```
           [,1]     [,2]     [,3]
 [1,]  0.057479 0.512632 0.423109
 [2,] -0.149431 0.455704 0.174755
 [3,] -0.217623 0.315060 0.280973
 [4,] -0.012548 0.408923 0.431337
 [5,]  0.037205 0.726578 0.300998
 [6,] -0.198987 0.301178 0.333882
 [7,]  0.012198 0.438064 0.428900
 [8,] -0.007949 0.670635 0.201780
 [9,]  0.072704 0.586991 0.412674
[10,] -0.191775 0.413161 0.192841
```

and the other dataframe is

```
           [,1]     [,2]     [,3]
 [1,]  0.184931 0.448481 0.066145
 [2,]  0.184866 0.454394 0.054991
 [3,]  0.184128 0.473572 0.045406
 [4,]  0.180612 0.492263 0.035785
 [5,]  0.173571 0.511862 0.034852
 [6,]  0.162665 0.526397 0.033614
 [7,]  0.151182 0.539169 0.031943
 [8,]  0.140002 0.553121 0.028965
 [9,]  0.129629 0.569350 0.025923
[10,]  0.119663 0.580098 0.037508
```

Comment: Can you provide the code and data that you have used?

Comment: @slamballais I've edited my question, I hope it will be more clear.

Comment: Please add also an example data set.

Comment: @tpetzoldt I added it. Thanks for your attention.

Comment: .. maybe these examples could help you get started https://www.r-graph-gallery.com/3d_scatter_plot.html

Comment: @EricFail thank you so much. But I already drew the plots that I have posted (in my question) with the help of this post that I found on the net.

Comment: Got it. Thank. Maybe you could elaborate your question so that we have [a complete minimal reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), i.e. with easy access to the example data, to go along with your question. Something we can work from and use to show you how it might be possible to answer your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I still don`t understand what is meant with "correlated" in your question, so the following may only answer parts of the question. But it shows one possible way how to provide reproducible data and how to combine and connect points in package "rgl".

```
library("rgl")

A <- matrix(c(
   0.057479, -0.149431, -0.217623,
  -0.012548,  0.037205, -0.198987,
   0.012198, -0.007949,  0.072704,
  -0.191775,  0.512632,  0.455704,
   0.315060,  0.408923,  0.726578,
   0.301178,  0.438064,  0.670635,
   0.586991,  0.413161,  0.423109,
   0.174755,  0.280973,  0.431337,
   0.300998,  0.333882,  0.4289,
   0.201780,  0.412674,  0.192841), ncol=3)

B <- matrix(c(
  0.184931, 0.448481, 0.066145,
  0.184866, 0.454394, 0.054991,
  0.184128, 0.473572, 0.045406,
  0.180612, 0.492263, 0.035785,
  0.173571, 0.511862, 0.034852,
  0.162665, 0.526397, 0.033614,
  0.151182, 0.539169, 0.031943,
  0.140002, 0.553121, 0.028965,
  0.129629, 0.569350, 0.025923,
  0.119663, 0.580098, 0.037508), ncol = 3)

# creates 3D plot
plot3d(x = A[, 1], y = A[, 2], z = A[, 3],
  type = 's',  col = "blue",  radius = .01,
  xlim = c(-0.3, 0.5),
  ylim = c( 0.3, 0.8),
  zlim = c( 0,   0.6),
  xlab = "x", ylab = "y", zlab = "z")

# adds points
plot3d(x = B[, 1], y = B[, 2], z = B[, 3],
       type = 's',  col = "green",
       radius = .01, add = TRUE)

# connects points
segments3d(x = rbind(A[, 1], B[, 1]), 
           y = rbind(A[, 2], B[, 2]), 
           z = rbind(A[, 3], B[, 3]))
```

[image: connected 3d points]

Comment: Thanks a million. It's exactly what I looked for. Thank you.